# Missing Microsoft.Threading.Tasks with azure SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I'm attempting to use the [Microsoft Azure SDK for .net](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net) version 0.9.5-preview. I am basically attempting to just get the sample for listing locations and services from the Readme working. However I'm running into an exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Information about this assembly is pretty sparse. I've found some references to it in relation to PCLs and windows phone but this is just a console application using the full 4.5.1(although I have also tried 4.5).

I've found a copy of the dll in a [google repository](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/ThirdParty/Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll?r=330e1e2f07758b8536fecbeda4205346b5fbc3ab) and throwing that in the bin directory does make the application work, however that seems like a spectacular hack. I'd rather see a better solution. Any ideas?

The packages.config contents are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common" version="0.9.8-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management" version="0.9.5-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute" version="0.9.9-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries" version="0.9.6-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring" version="0.9.2-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler" version="0.9.8-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceBus" version="0.9.3-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql" version="0.9.4-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage" version="0.9.3-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.VirtualNetworks" version="0.9.3-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites" version="0.9.3-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: I thought the latest version of the "Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET" is 2.2.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn459835.aspx) Is there a subset of that that you're using?

Comment: As I understand it, and I may well be wrong, this is an open source .net wrapper around the RESTful management API. Does the standard SDK allow for programatically configuring new servers and the such?

Comment: The Microsoft Azure SDK 2.2 provides a managed API (wrapping the REST interfaces) for many things (Tables, Blobs, Queues), but not Service Management (yet?)--which made me wonder about "0.9.5".  This seems like a version of something other than "Microsoft Azure SDK"...  I've done a bit of stuff with the management REST API, but didn't know they had a managed API for it... Maybe the 0.9.5 refers to only the Management API?

Comment: I believe that is accurate. I poked around the code and it lives largely in a  management namespace. Brady Gaster writes about it a bit on his blog http://www.bradygaster.com/post/managing-web-sites-from-web-sites-using-the-windows-azure-management-libraries-for-net

Comment: Which NuGet package are you using?

Comment: @JeffWilcox I did an install of Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries -Pre which gave me what I've added to the question.

Comment: It is happening to me. I am installing through NuGet UI. Opened an issue. https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/464

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Microsoft.Threading.Tasks` assembly you are missing is in `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package. Not sure why but your `packages.config` file is missing a bunch of dependent assemblies. You may want to un-install and install again your NuGet packages to bring back the dependencies.

Comment: There is a missing dependency in the nuget configuration for this package. I've submitted a pull request and hopefully this will go away in the next release.

Comment: Thanks very much! This solution really help me! now I use 1.0.3 version still have this problem! MS will close down if they still hire the developer/Tester like Azure Nuget team member!

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that you have the latest versions of the dependent assemblies from the dependencies NuGet package, installed with `-Pre`?

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies/